# Is there a way to write "$@" to a new file from a Makefile?

Tags: makefile

I've been trying to create an executable file from a Makefile to run a java program and I need the executable to have the text: java program $@. This is so any arguments will be passed into the program when it runs.

From the Makefile, I've been trying to echo into the new file:

```
@echo "java Program $@" >> exec
```

However, $@ results in "all" being written to exec, and $$@ becomes blank when written to exec. Is there another way to escape this sequence in a Makefile? I essentially need it to ignore $@.

I appreciate your time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`$$` is the correct way to escape the `$` for Make, but the result is then being expanded by Bash.  Try this:

```
@echo 'java Program $$@' >> exec
```

Single quotes in Bash mean that variables don't get expanded.